# Simple rings/algebras fail to be division rings/algebras because of zero-divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Is the following statement true/false?

> For a non-trivial ring $R$, and a maximal modular ideal $M\subset R$, if $M$ is *not* one-sided maximal, then the non-invertible elements of the quotient $R/M$ are zero-divisors.

I know if an ideal is *left*-maximal or *right*-maximal, then the quotient must be a division ring. But want to understand why this fails when it's only maximal. Do simple rings/algebras fail to be division rings/algebras *only* because of zero-divisors? I'm aware of this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2514200/416552), but that only shows an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what "maximal ideal not one-sided maximal" is supposed to mean. You're saying it's maximal as a two-sided ideal, not as a one-sided ideal?  And you mean it's modular both as a left and a right ideal?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes. That's what I mean. So $M$ is two-sided maximal. But there is a larger proper one-sided ideal containing $M$. And yes, it is two-sided modular, so the quotient is unital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then the non-invertible elements of the quotient /
> are zero-divisors.

No, it doesn't follow. For example, the [Weyl algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra) is a ring (with identity) without nonzero zero divisors, and it is also a simple ring.  The zero ideal is maximal (and modular of course, as are all ideals in a ring with identity) but not maximal as a left or right ideal.

Comment: [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=3&H=8&L=63l) for simple domains that aren't division rings.

Comment: Thanks. But then is it possible to modify the OP and makes it correct? Maybe it's true if it's changed to something like, "the non-invertible elements of the quotient is of the form $a+\alpha$, where $a$ is invertible but $\alpha$ is a nonzero zero-divisor"? Or maybe some other form? There must be some relations to zero divisors?

Comment: "$a+\alpha$ where $a$ is invertible and $\alpha$ is a nonzero zero divisor" surely won't work: in the example given above there are no choices for $\alpha$.  In a ring where nonzero zero divisors don't exist, your quest to associate them with elements outside the maximal ideal is going to be fruitless.

Comment: Finding, for a given ring, a way to describe the noninvertible elements is going to be as hard as describing the invertible elements. In general, there is no magic expression for either.

Comment: Thanks. Can I understand it as this? We can always think of a ring as a free algebra quotient-ing out some relations. So if the ring has a pair of invertible elements $(a,b)$ such that $ab=ba=1$, it is quotient of the free algebra of some generators quotient out that relations. Similarly if there're zero-divisors $ab=0$, then the ring is the quotient of some free algebra over that relation. So it's always possible to start from some free algebra and choose some relations to quotient out, producing invertibles or zero-divisors. And there's no restriction whatsoever?

Comment: I mean, maybe not free algebra. But a "free ring".

Comment: @user760 Yes: at the very worst, you can treat each individual element of your ring as a free generator in the free ring. If you map these generators back into your old ring with the obvious map, the kernel necessarily contains all the relations needed to describe your original ring.

Comment: So the real efforts should be about understanding the ideals and one-sided ideals of free algebras/rings. I still have a question though. In a free algebra/ring, it seems at no step did we define a "unit". So does every free algebra/ring automatically admits a two-sided modular ideal, and quotient-ing that ideal out generates a unital ring? Maybe I misunderstood something. I mean, you could say the "empty word" is a unit when concatenating with all the other words. But it seems the "empty word" isn't an element?

Comment: @user760 Well I have never dealt with nonunital free algebras, but yes, I imagine that including the empty word would be a way to give it an identity. It could also be defined using just the generators and finite sums of their finite products, without identity too, I suppose.

Comment: If the free algebra we start with is always unital, then we can't produce non-unital algebras after quotient-ing out any ideals. Right?

Comment: @user760 Yes, fair enough.  I guess you do need the unitless construction.